# Iterating the Series.str.contain function with an AND condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, contains

I have the following series:

```
series = pd.Series(['ABC', 'AAABBB', 'BBBCCSSS', 'AABBCC'])
```

and I would like to check if each string contains A, B and C. Such as:

```
x = (series.str.contains('A')) & (series.str.contains('B')) & (series.str.contains('C'))
```

However I would like to be able to adjust the contents of the contains() function with a list like `items = ['A', 'B', 'C']` or `items = ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']` etc.. which would build the above variable `x`.

How could I create the variable `x` iteratively using the list?

Comment: Maybe `np.array([series.str.contains(i) for i in items]).all(axis=0)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most efficient approach, so if you're comparing large amounts of data it may not be a workable solution, but
it is possible to build a single regex.

```
series = pd.Series(['ABC', 'AAABBB', 'BBBCCSSS', 'AABBCC'])
items = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

- A way to say **AND** in regex terms is to use multiple lookahead assertions: `(?=)`
- [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape metacharacters (e.g `.`,  `+`, etc)

```
''.join(f'(?=.*{re.escape(item)})' for item in items)
```

```
(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C)
```

```
import re

pattern = ''.join(f'(?=.*{re.escape(item)})' for item in items)

series.str.contains(pattern)
```

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

---

#### rapidfuzz

If you are comparing large amounts of data and speed if of a concern, [rapidfuzz](/questions/tagged/rapidfuzz) may be of interest.

You can use [`.cdist()`](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/Usage/process.html) to compare everything in parallel and check all the scores are greater than 0:

```
(rapidfuzz.process.cdist(items, series, workers=-1) > 0).all(axis=0)
```

```
array([ True, False, False,  True])
```

Comment: This is a nice trick but the regex is inefficient. For each position it will read the rest of the string to try to find all words. So if you have a long string, many words and/or many duplicates this will quickly become hard to compute (quadratic complexity).

Comment: Compare for instance [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/udwToI/1) and a [simple `A|B|C`](https://regex101.com/r/cVO3kE/1) to extract all individual words. The numbers of steps is >1000 in the first case, ~100 in the second.

Comment: @mozway Good point, thank you. This is definitely something I should have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) the words then count of the number of unique words (with [`groupby.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html)) matches the number of unique items.

```
import re

items = ['A', 'B', 'C']

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, items))

out = (series
 .str.extractall(f'({pattern})')[0]
 .groupby(level=0).nunique().eq(len(set(items)))
 )
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```